# How does X-server calculate DPI?

Tags: xorg, x11, display-settings, resolution, x-server

From [Xfce Docs](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-settings/appearance#dpi):

> In case you want to override the DPI (dots per inch) value *calculated
>   by the X-server*, you can select the checkbox and use the spin box to
>   specify the resolution to use when your screen renders fonts.

But *how* does X-server do its calculation?  What assumptions are made in the process and can some of the parameters be overridden?

It may know how many pixels I have on my display, but is that enough?

Answer (score 12):

As far as I know,  starting with version 1.7, `xorg` [defaults to `96 dpi`](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23705). It doesn't calculate anything unless you specify `DisplaySize` via `Xorg` config files. Also, don't rely on `xdpyinfo` output.
My laptop runs on Intel SandyBridge. Excerpt from my `Xorg.0.log` on a fresh Archlinux install:

```
(==) intel(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
```

running

```
xdpyinfo | grep -E 'dimensions|resolution'
```

returns:

```
dimensions:    1600x900 pixels (423x238 millimeters)
resolution:    96x96 dots per inch
```

which is far from being true. I [know](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67983/get-monitor-make-and-model-and-other-info-in-human-readable-form/68241#68241) that my screen size is `344x193` mm so obviously `xdpyinfo` calculates the physical size based on pixel resolution (`1600x900`) and default `96 DPI`. If I add

```
........
DisplaySize     344 193
........
```

in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/monitor.conf` and restart, `Xorg.0.log` correctly reports:

```
(**) intel(0): Display dimensions: (344, 193) mm
(**) intel(0): DPI set to (118, 118)
```

However, `xdpyinfo | grep -E 'dimensions|resolution'` always returns:

```
dimensions:    1600x900 pixels (423x238 millimeters)
resolution:    96x96 dots per inch
```

Still, no visual changes as I'm using Gnome, and `96 DPI` is also hard-coded in `gnome-settings-daemon`. After patching the latter, I can enjoy my native `118 DPI`. But even after all that, `xdpyinfo` still returns:

```
dimensions:    1600x900 pixels (423x238 millimeters)
resolution:    96x96 dots per inch
```

Comment: Thanks. How does wayland calculate it? Does it also assume 96 DPI? Where would you override it under gnome-shell / mutter?

Comment: @Bram - afaik `wayland` assumes `96` DPI for apps that don’t handle scaling... keep in mind that some apps don't fully support `wayland`  and as such they rely on `xwayland`... That being said, iirc there used to be a setting available via `gsettings` where you could tweak the scaling... I'm afraid I can't help you more as we stopped using Gnome about 4 years ago (when we migrated everything to KDE - we're still using X11 backend so I haven't got into `wayland` much yet)

Answer (score 8):

> How does X-server calculate DPI?

The DPI of the X server is determined in the following manner:

1. The `-dpi` command line option has highest priority.
2. If this is not used, the `DisplaySize` setting in the X config file is used to derive the DPI, given the screen resolution.
3. If no `DisplaySize` is given, the monitor size values from DDC are used to derive the DPI, given the screen resolution.
4. If DDC does not specify a size, 75 DPI is used by default.

> It may know how many pixels I have on my display, but is that enough?

No, it not only knows the virtual screen size in pixel but (usually) also physical display size in millimeters. You can check your display dimensions by running the following in a terminal window:

```
 ~ $ xdpyinfo | grep dimension
dimensions:    1366x768 pixels (361x203 millimeters)
```

The calculation which is your X server doing is the following:

- 1366 pixels divided by 361 millimeters multiplied with 25.4 millimeters per inch = 96.11191136 dots per inch (DPI).
- 768 pixels divided by 203 millimeters multiplied with 25.4 millimeters per inch = 96.09458128 dots per inch.

You can check what DPI your X server has calculated using the following command:

```
 ~ $ xdpyinfo | grep resolution
 resolution:    96x96 dots per inch
```

Looks good, doesn't it?

For further reading:

- http://scanline.ca/dpi/
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg#Display_Size_and_DPI
- http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-find-out-screen-resolution-of-my-linux-desktop/

Comment: @alois-mahdal I guess I misunderstood the question at first. I've improved the answer adding the display dimensions used by X server.

Comment: Xorg defaults to 96x96 regardless of monitor resolution. I think this is because programs supply images meant for this standard dpi.  It's better to be a little off than to create artifacts by scaling images all the time. My primary monitor's actual DPI is 93.8.  However, setting custom DPI is useful for large displays such as large HDTVs whose DPI are much lower than 96.

Comment: X doesn't seem to allow per-monitor DPI settings for a single screen, that DPI is shared across all monitors in the same screen. Also I found that the millimeters given by `xdpyinfo` does not add up from millimeters from `xrandr --query`.

Answer (score -1):

Dots Per Inch = Dots ( pixels ) / Inches ( physical size of monitor ).