# Why does xdpyinfo and xrandr give different measurements?

Tags: xrandr, monitors, resolution

I'm trying to calculate the size of my 2 screens together.

Using `xdpyinfo`, I see the following:

`xdpyinfo  | grep 'dimensions:'
  dimensions:    5120x1600 pixels (1355x423 millimeters)`

However, individually `xrandr` shows:

```
xrandr | grep ' connected'
DP-4.8 connected 2560x1600+2560+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 641mm x 401mm
DP-6 connected primary 2560x1600+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 641mm x 401mm
```

What could explain this difference?
641m + 641m != 1355m  (difference: 72mm)
401m != 423m (difference: 22mm)

Is one of them including the bezel of the monitor and the other is not?

Comment: No, it's simply that `xdpyinfo` is wrong. That's a long [story](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23705). See also [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75344/how-does-x-server-calculate-dpi).