# Finding the brightness and R,G,B combination being used in a desktop monitor

Tags: ubuntu, multi-monitor, brightness

I have two desktop computers.

The first one is:
Lenovo.
Description: Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS,
Release: 16.04,
codename: xenial.

The second one is:
Dell Inspiron.
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS,
Release: 18.04,
codename: bionic.

The first desktop has a comfortable brightness level. It does not require any special applications.

For the second desktop, I have to use an application called “Brightness Controller”. In this application, I have to adjust four items: Brightness, R, G and B. I tried many combinations of the four items. But could not get the exact screen appearance as the first desktop.

Is there a way to find out the “combination of the four items” that is being used in the first computer? Then I will be able to make the second computer also appear the same.
Thanks.

Comment: look into EDID - extended displai identification data.  in linux I've heard of `read-edid`.  Also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67983/get-monitor-make-and-model-and-other-info-in-human-readable-form

Comment: Are these desktops or laptops? If desktops, what are the monitors (screens) you are using? Are you sure the screen can do what you want?

Comment: @ron I was thinking about a simple application like the "xgamma" command. It gives the R,G,B values. But not the brightness value. If I get the brightness also, I can use the slider for brightness in "Brightness controller". Also I would like to adjust the color temperature in "Brightness controller". So I want the current color temperature also, that is being used in my first desktop.

Comment: @terdon These are desktops. They are LED monitors. Using the application "Brightness controller", I am able to adjust color, brightness and temperature using the appropriate sliders. But the problem is that, I do not know where to put the sliders so as to get the same appearance as my first desktop.